# useContext is giving undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I'm trying to pass value from my parent component for making some API call. I'm using context to pass the value between two components but I'm getting undefined in the console log. Could you guys please help me.

**Parent component.**

```
import Travel from './Travel'

export const TransactionAccountIdContext = createContext();

export default function Accounts() {

  const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState(0);
  const setTransactionAccountId = e => {
    console.log("Clicked ID", e.currentTarget.value);
    setAccountId(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        value={account.id}
        onClick={setTransactionAccountId}
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<ReceiptIcon />}
      >
        Show Transactions
      </Button>
      <TransactionAccountIdContext.Provider value={"1212121"}>
        <Travel />
      </TransactionAccountIdContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**child component (Travel.jsx)**

```
import TransactionAccountIdContext from "./accounts";

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const accountId = useContext(TransactionAccountIdContext);
  console.log("accountId", accountId);

  return <h1>{accountId}</h1>;
}
```

I'm also making some API calls using react hooks in parent and child components but I have removed it here to reduce the size of the question. Could anyone of you please tell us what can be the issue.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit. Does `console.log("accountId", accountId);` say undefined or `return <h1>{accountId}</h1>;` return undefined value for accountId. Also where is the `MaterialTableDemo` component rendered

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri im getting undefined in `console.log("accountId", accountId)` and `MaterialTableDemo` is rendered in parent component as Travel. I have added import statement for more clarity.

Comment: Your code seems fine, I'm sure there is something you not showing us which leads to this behavior, please make a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-60473444-fixopcode-hd8gb

Comment: sure @DennisVash. I will publish my code in sandbox ASAP. Thanks

Comment: try to destructure the imported context eg: import { TransactionAccountIdContext } from './accounts'. i think that'll solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to your import syntax in `Travel.jsx`.

Your `TransactionAccountIdContext` is being exported from the parent as a named constant. It needs to be destructured from the import in the child component.

eg:

```js
/// Travel.jsx
import { TransactionAccountIdContext } from "./accounts";
```